# How to change the number of Administration Views results in the Drupal back end?

Tags: views, users

How can I change the number of list items (results), using Drupal's back end?

Is it possible to filter how many results, instead of having multiple pages of items? Something to select like 10, 50, 100, 500, ALL? Should be a simple setting, but can't find it.

I've installed [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views), but it's a pain since I have to adjust a dozen views, one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such thing as a "global setting" within Drupal administration (what you call "back end") to set such "how many results".

The only way to do so (assuming you use Drupal 7), is to perform these steps for each of the individual views where you want to set "how many results" you want:

- Use the Views UI to edit the view.
- In the 2nd column, within *Pager*:

  - Use pager:  use the options "Display a specified number of items".
  - Pager options: set the "Items per page" to "how many results" you want.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, I guess I will have to live with clicking next..I have installed admin views, (and yes, it works perfectly) but with all the complexity of the site and dependencies it seems to break things up (exposed filters ect...) Is there a way to change these settings in PHP my admin?

Comment: I'm not aware of such setting in PhpMyAdmin either, sorry. Maybe create a feature request in the modules issue queue?

Comment: Hi Pierre, nope, not aware of anything actually I'm struggling to even learn about this site, I'll read the link you sent me for sure, thanks.

Comment: OK, don't worry, that's why I started to wonder (and dared to ask ...). Getting started with Drupal.SE isn't obvious I think. Especially to find out what is appropriate to ask (or answer), and what is not, and what people are expecting from newbees. Moreover there are so many thing to be aware of, to discover, etc ... Would you agree on that? BUT: it's worth learning and discovering, step by step, day by day. Because in the end it's a great Drupal resource, and community (if you can live with the things you don't like, like I do also ...)

Comment: Just 1 sample of what I mean by "learning and discovering": there seems to be a rule on any SE-site that you can only ask 30 questions during 50 days (forgot where I ever read that, but I did see it somewhere) ... I thought about it when I noticed that "you" asked 4 questions only today ...